# PowerShell to find accidental double file extensions

Tags: powershell

I have some users that occasionally accidentally double append a file extension to a file and have been trying to figure out how to script this in powershell.

E.G. The user names a file "document123.docx.docx" but they have visible file extensions disabled on their machine so they assume the file name is "document123.docx" How can I search for double appended file extensions so that this can be easily identified?

This only affects program code that expects the exact file to be named "document123.docx"and since it doesn’t exist it is unable to continue.

Comment: I would suggest looking into a regular expression to catch three characters, a dot, then three more characters.

Comment: See [this Q&A on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42424644/how-to-display-only-the-double-extension-file-instead-of-all-files)

Answer (score 3):

To find files with the same extension doubled, try:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\* -Recurse -File | 
    Where-Object{$_.Extension -and $_.BaseName -like "*$($_.Extension)"}
```

To automatically remove the doubled extension:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\* -Recurse -File | 
    Where-Object{$_.Extension -and $_.BaseName -like "*$($_.Extension)"}|
        Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName} -WhatIf
```

If the output looks OK, remove the trailing `-WhatIf`

Answer (score 0):

The script would work fine if I was in a folder that I wanted to check but when checking from C:\ it would error and quit because it would not have enough rights even run as Admin when it would hit some nested folders inside of C:\Windows so I excluded that folder and then to suppress non-exiting errors I added the silently continue option like below.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\* -Recurse -File -Exclude "C:\Windows\" -EA SilentlyContinue| 
    Where-Object{$_.Extension -and $_.BaseName -like "*$($_.Extension)"}
```